# Convert txt file to csv and ignore specific text Line

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

[image: TXT file output]

```bsh
$userObj = [PSCustomObject]((Get-Content -Raw C:\Automation\sam.txt) -replace ':', '=' | ConvertFrom-StringData)
$name = Get-Item C:\Automation\sam.txt | Select-Object -ExpandProperty BaseName
$userObj | Export-Csv C:\Automation\$name.csv
```

I am using the above script to convert txt file to CSV but I don't know how to exclude word Line with underlined characters .

The script works if I delete "Line  ---- " and try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skip the first 2 lines when importing the file:

```
$data = (Get-Content 'C:\path\to\input.txt') -replace ':', '=' |
        Select-Object -Skip 2 |
        Out-String |
        ConvertFrom-StringData
[PSCustomObject]$data | Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\output.csv' -NoType
```

Better yet, change the process that creates your input file, so that it doesn't produce the offending header. The data seems to be generated by something like

```
... | Select-String ... | Select-Object Line | Set-Content ...
```

To remove the header from the output you just need to change `Select-Object Line` to `Select-Object -Expand Line`.